# How to break a bash script initiated with xbindkeys?

Tags: bash, shell-script, xdotool, xbindkeys

I initiated a bash script by xbindkeys as

```
"sleep 1;bash /home/scripts/loop.sh"
  KP_Add
```

How can I bind another key, which can break this bash script?

For example, if `loop.sh` is 1,000 clicks by pressing `KP_Add`, how can I break the bash loop after 200 clicks by pressing `KP_Substract`?

Comment: So you would try to interrupt the bash script with human reflexes? Or do you want to set a signal file (or alternative) so that loop.sh knows to stop at 200? Or???

Comment: @JeffSchaller either way works for me. I can put a condition in the bash script to be interrupted by a key (I don't know how to do so, because it is not in the terminal) OR bind a key in `xbindkey` to interrupt the running script. By the way, 200 is not a preset value. I just mean interrupting the script whenever needed before the end of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest binding a key to an action that kills the script:

```
"pkill -f bash /home/scripts/loop.sh"
```

The [pkill command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) above uses the `-f` option to match the given script name against the full process name; any matching process is then killed. I copied the script name directly from the KP_Add example you gave.